# How do I print out the first x amount of decimals/letters?

Tags: python

So basically if someone were to input a name and a number, I would like to create a username generated from the first 3 letters of someone's name and the last 3 digits of the number. I have everything set up, I just need to know how I would pull x amount of digits/letters from the users inputs.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say the name is "Bobby" and the number is 2014:

```
name="Bobby"
number=2014

numberAsString=str(2014) #cast as string 

print name[0:3] #gives you "Bob"
print numberAsString[-3:] #gives you "014"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
name = "Timothy"
number = 1234

username = "%s%s" % (name[:3], str(number)[-3:])

print username

# Prints Tim234
```